# Flask, Windows, IIS, Plotly-Dash. Error Occured While reading WSGI handler

Tags: python, iis, flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm hoping you can help me with errors that I'm getting with Flask in an attempt to deploy plotly-dash on a Windows server.

I've set up Flask using the following guide, verbatim, except the location of my website within the wwwroot folder:
[Flask on IIS](http://netdot.co/2015/03/09/flask-on-iis/)

When I use the most basic of apps, it works fine, an example being the following code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello from FastCGI via IIS!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

But then if I try something slightly more complex, like the basic Dash demo:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(
        id='example-graph',
        figure={
            'data': [
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [4, 1, 2], 'type': 'bar', 'name': 'SF'},
                {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': [2, 4, 5], 'type': 'bar', 'name': u'Montréal'},
            ],
            'layout': {
                'title': 'Dash Data Visualization'
            }
        }
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I get an error as follows (which I've tried to tidy up for ease of interpretation):

```
Error occurred while reading WSGI handler: 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
    File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wfastcgi.py", line 791, in main env, handler = read_wsgi_handler(response.physical_path) 
    File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wfastcgi.py", line 633, in read_wsgi_handler handler = get_wsgi_handler(os.getenv("WSGI_HANDLER")) 
    File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wfastcgi.py", line 600, in get_wsgi_handler handler = __import__(module_name, fromlist=[name_list[0][0]]) 
    File ".\app.py", line 1, in import dash 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\dash\__init__.py", line 1, in from .dash import Dash # noqa: F401 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 12, in import plotly 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\plotly\__init__.py", line 31, in from plotly import (plotly, dashboard_objs, graph_objs, grid_objs, tools, 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\__init__.py", line 10, in from . plotly import ( 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\plotly\plotly\plotly.py", line 30, in from plotly import exceptions, files, session, tools, utils 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py", line 59, in ipython_core_display = optional_imports.get_module('IPython.core.display') 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\plotly\optional_imports.py", line 23, in get_module return import_module(name) 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\__init__.py", line 55, in from .terminal.embed import embed 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\terminal\embed.py", line 15, in from IPython.core.interactiveshell import DummyMod, InteractiveShell 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 61, in from IPython.utils import io 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 95, in stdin = IOStream(sys.stdin, fallback=devnull) 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 39, in __init__ for meth in filter(clone, dir(stream)): 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 38, in clone return not hasattr(self, meth) and not meth.startswith('_') 
    File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\io.py", line 82, in closed return self.stream.closed 
    ValueError: underlying buffer has been detached StdOut: StdErr:
```

I've done a ton of googling and tried my best to decode this error, but I'm hitting a brick wall. Does anyone have any ideas?

Following on from the suggestion by @susodapop I've removed IPython and now got the following error:

```
Error occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wfastcgi.py", line 847, in main result = handler(record.params, response.start) 
TypeError: 'Dash' object is not callable StdOut: StdErr: C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\plotly\tools.py:103: UserWarning: Looks like you don't have 'read-write' permission to your 'home' ('~') directory or to our '~/.plotly' directory. 
That means plotly's python api can't setup local configuration files. No problem though! You'll just have to sign-in using 'plotly.plotly.sign_in()'. For help with that: 'help(plotly.plotly.sign_in)'. Questions? Visit https://support.plot.ly
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Microsoft's blessed version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wfastcgi) of `wfastcgi.py` and its accompanying configuration instructions. Older versions of `wfastcgi.py` had issues with trying to write binary output to a non-binary object, which is similar to what you're seeing here.

Until recently, the instructions available online for configuring Flask with IIS were all a bit confusing. Microsoft's own solution is the easiest to configure unless you're using Azure.

Comment: tried that with no luck. still getting the same error

Comment: It looks like the root problem is the "optional_imports" module in plotly. Code here: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/blob/master/plotly/optional_imports.py. To further debug, I would add an "except ValueError: continue" statement and see what happens. It's possible you have an underlying issue with your IPython installation.

Comment: ok thanks - is it worth me just re-installing python? i've had to copy the libs from another python installation instead of installing via pip because of firewall restrictions, could this be the root cause?

Comment: You probably don't need to reinstall Python itself. Just the IronPython extension since it's the package that is throwing the error. If you can't use pip, you can download the package from pythonhosted, save it to your site-packages directory and then manually run it's setup.py instead.

Comment: that works! I've just uninstalled IPython - I've got a new error though.  Is this just related to windows folder permissions? i'll put it in the main post

Comment: Correct. For Flask apps to run properly on IIS you need to have read-write permissions for IUSR and <your-domain>\IIS_IUSRS in your entire module directory. You can change the permissions in IIS Manager by navigating to your site in the toolbar. Right-click and chose 'Edit Permissions". Under the "Security" tab, click "Edit" and add users.

Comment: thanks again, this has somehow killed the site -_- I'm just getting a "the website cannot display the page" error now. the weird thing is that on first load, i get the python error but on subsequent refreshes i just get the standard error message mentioned above.

Comment: Have you enabled Flask debugger? To do so, set the FLASK_DEBUG=1 environment variable. This should give more insight into what’s failing.

Comment: I have, I always have had but don't know where to find the debug log / interpret it. I really don't want to give up but I seem to be hitting a brick wall!

Comment: I feel your pain! The "the website cannot display the page" is a 500 error. If the Flask Debugger is enabled, it will tell you exactly which line of your script caused the page failure. I should have asked before: are you using the Flask development server or something like gunicorn? What happens if you use 'Flask Run' in the CLI? The flask debugger doesn't save logs in a separate file, it displays an interactive debugger in the browser any time there is a page load failure.

Comment: i've just installed flask using pip, i think it came as a dependency for plotly. the main error I'm getting is still the permissions one (even after I've set permissions) but the annoying thing now is as soon as i hit f5 to refresh the page I get the http 500 error, it doesnt seem to load the script up again.  In regards to the CLI, i've tried that in the command prompt, powershell and python console and basically just get different syntax errors (i've tried the variations that are required for each type)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170333/discussion-between-susodapop-and-roastbeeef).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues. Here are the steps I ran to get this to work:

1) Ensure there is no spaces between the python.exe, pipe, and wfastcgi.py file in the "Add Module Mapping" Executable. See this [link](https://medium.com/@bilalbayasut/deploying-python-web-app-flask-in-windows-server-iis-using-fastcgi-6c1873ae0ad8) for explanation. This threw a 500 error for me.

2) Ensure you are using the flask app instance instead of the dash app instance. See [Dash Deployment User Guide](https://dash.plot.ly/deployment) This is accomplished by using app.server instead of app.app in the WSGI_HANDLER environment variable. Screenshots in link from 1.

3) Lastly, uninstall IPython as indicated in comments if you get the error from the original question.

After these three issues. I got my dash app to deploy on IIS.