# Dash App on IIS Webserver Timing Out with HTTP500 SC258 Error

Tags: iis, webserver, plotly-dash, iis-10

I have ISS Server hosting Dash app.

[image]

What I am noticing in the browser is that app starts but doesn't return anything back. Looking at the HTTP logs, it shows HTTP 500 error with sc-win32-status 258. Timetaken value from HTTP logs is around 100seconds.

There are HTTP 200 with same time taken value...so that tells me its not only timeout issue. I didn't change the default timeout value in IIS (which I think is more than 5 mins?)

Trying to figure out what is causing this intermittent timeout issue.

Thanks!

Comment: did you configure the handler mapping in iis for the python site? assign iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the site folder. [link1](https://dash.plotly.com/deployment) ,[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58980691/cant-get-dash-app-run-on-iis-with-flask-server) ,[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49814358/flask-windows-iis-plotly-dash-error-occured-while-reading-wsgi-handler)

Comment: I request you to mark the helpful suggestion as an answer. This will help other people who face the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the timeout duration in **IIS > FastCGI Settings > Process Model > Activity Timeout**.
The operation was taking long time then it was set to communication with IIS.

Increasing the timeout to 180seconds seemed to fix the issue for me.